# Android - NullReferenceException on Scroll/Drag-and-Drop (setDragFocus)

Tags: android, xamarin, drag-and-drop, crash, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on an Android App using Xamarin.Android (C#).

I have developed a drag-and-drop autoscroll listview, as seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/PiMaker/0d1572aa532ca67c39259dc5e33aac83).

It works amazingly well, but sometimes, just sometimes, it crashes and leaves no clue why. An exception is thrown "in unmanaged code" and the only useful information that the debugger shows is this stacktrace:

```
--- End of managed Java.Lang.NullPointerException stack trace ---
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewRootImpl.setDragFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1454)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDragEvent(ViewGroup.java:1482)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleDragEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5337)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.access$600(ViewRootImpl.java:108)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3464)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5497)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I don't really suspect you can tell me why this is happening, but maybe, is there a way to at least debug this properly?

Nowhere, not even in the log, does it say anything about a fault in my application, it just crashes. Boom and gone.

Comment: I looked at your `XamarinScrollableListView` I do not see anything wrong in it. I would ***assume*** something is getting garbage collected outside of that class, but that is a wild swing in the dark unless you can make/post a test case for it...

Answer (score 0):

The error say that you have a null object reference. Check the object that generate the problem and watch is correctly instantiated.

example

```
//this object is null

Object some

Mymethod(some)

//this object is not null

Object some = new Object()

Mymethod(some)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's where the problem arises. If only I knew where that "Object some" were. The mono runtime is not showing me any helpful exception trace. I even tried surrounding almost my entire code with try...catch - to no avail.

Comment: try debug the application with breakpoint condition or actions in the case of action write some message in the console...

Comment: Same problem again, where do I set the breakpoint/write the debug statement?

Answer (score 0):

in the option in the red square. Set the breakpoint/write

[image: Breakpoint/Write]

Java.Lang.NullPointerException I associate this at overflow error if the pointer or if you access a list does not exist or is greater than the number of nodes can give this error checks that.